# Transmuting a #[repr(align(...))] padded struct to a &[u8] without causing UB

Tags: rust, initialization, undefined-behavior, memory-alignment

In GLSL, a `vec3` is required to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary when used in a uniform block. In order to represent this requirement, I have a Rust type defined as follows:

```rust
#[repr(C, align(16))]
struct UniformVec3([f32; 3]);
```

This makes it easier to construct uniform data on the CPU side without having to manually specify padding. However, in order to upload the data to the GPU, the struct has to be transmuted to a `&[u8]`, like this:

```rust
let v = UniformVec3([1.0, 0.0, 0.0]);

unsafe {
    let as_bytes = std::slice::from_raw_parts(
        (&v as *const UniformVec3) as *const u8,
        std::size_of::<UniformVec3>(),
    );

    // do stuff with as_bytes...
}
```

As it stands, this is undefined behavior because the bit pattern of the four bytes of padding is undefined. My question is: is there some way to initialize this struct (with its current definition!) without invoking UB upon transmuting it to a `&[u8]`? Or do I have to insert explicit padding in the struct, which will be defined at initialization?

Comment: By "bit pattern" you mean endianness, right? Then it usually the job of the GPU library (e.g. `cudaMemcpy`) to handle that.

Comment: @Kitsu no they mean literally the contents of the struct, they have 12 bytes of actual content in a 16 bytes struct so there are 4 bytes of padding which contain uninitialised memory.

Comment: Or, that makes sense then. But why do you need a `&[u8]` slice? For FFI you only need a pointer, isn't it?

Comment: @Kitsu this is GPGPU stuff so the API probably want a "data buffer" which is always a bunch of bytes.

Comment: "data buffer" in C API is simply a pointer (+ length if you need to pass more multiple `UniformVec3`).

Comment: Is it possible to keep it as a `(*const u8, usize)` pair? Then you don't have to worry if any of it is initialized or not.

Comment: Is this actually undefined behavior? I don't believe so. On the glsl side, there is going to be a  `vec3` which has access to only the first 12 bytes of data, ignoring the remaining 4 bytes. It would be undefined behavior if the uniform buffer was a `vec3` and a `float` and you tried to access the data on the `float` which has access to the remaining 4 bytes which is padding. If you want to avoid the padded data to be random but have a well defined value, you could use `std::mem::zeroed`.

Comment: @LambdaFairy the API I'm using (`wgpu`) requires a `&[u8]`

Comment: @AndreaNardi UB is triggered on the Rust side as soon as the `&[u8]` is constructed, see [behavior considered undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html): "An integer (i*/u*)...obtained from uninitialized memory." Initializing it with `mem::zeroed()` solves that particular issue, but I still don't know if the language *guarantees* that it will work correctly.

Comment: I suggest you create the data as a byte buffer initialized to 0 in the first place, and then transmute it to `&mut UniformVec3` to work on it. Once you are done, you send the original buffer to the FFI call.